# Using binary file to deal with compressed data

Tags: c++, file, compression

I have this code that deals with files to save the compressed values and then read the compressed file to decompress it, in this way it works very fine!
this is just a part of my code:

```
void func1(){
  unsigned int const Qsz = 5 * NRB+15;
  unsigned char Qchar[Qsz]; // this array has the compressed values after compreesion 
  ofstream Resfile;
  Resfile.open("C://Compressedfile.fr", ios::binary | ios::out);
  Resfile.write((char *)Qchar, (Qsz) * sizeof(char));
  Resfile.close();
}

void func2(){
  ifstream Resfile;
  Resfile.open("C://Compressedfile.fr", ios::binary | ios::in);
  unsigned char NRBst[2];
  Resfile.read((char *)NRBst, 2 * sizeof(char));
  unsigned int const Qsz = (5 * NRB)+13;
  unsigned char Qchar[Qsz];
  Resfile.read((char*)Qchar, Qsz * sizeof(char));
  Resfile.close(); 
}
```

I am wondering what this meant?

```
unsigned char NRBst[2];

Resfile.read((char *)NRBst, 2 * sizeof(char));
```

and why when I commented it, the code gave me an incorrect result?
Note that it is not used anywhere else in the code!

**First update**

```
unsigned int const Qsz = 5 * NRB+15;
unsigned char Qchar[Qsz]; // this array has the compressed values 

void func1(){
 
 // Here, there are some processing on my data to get on compressed data
 // and then save it in Qchar[Qsz]
  Qchar[Qsz];
}
void func2(){ 
  //unsigned char NRBst[2];
  //Resfile.read((char *)NRBst, 2 * sizeof(char));
  unsigned int const Qsz1 = (5 * NRB)+13;
  Qchar[Qsz1];
}
```

Comment: It means it skips the first two characters (almost certainly bytes) of the file. This is not much of a question as it stands now.

Comment: It seems rather obvious that the code that writes it, writes `5 * NRB+15` bytes, and the reading code reads `2`, then `5 * NRB+13` bytes. The End.

Comment: Stackoverflow usage note: *this is just a part of my code* is usually an unforced error.  To be able to verify answers we often need a runnable example, a [mre]. Posting representative snippets usually isn't good enough.

Comment: Side note. `sizeof(char)` is always 1. No exceptions. Even if `char` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The read line is taking the first 2 bytes from the incoming stream and just putting them into a garbage buffer. If its not being used anywhere else then it was probably padding or meta data. The reason it fails when you comment it out is because now you're reading a different part of the stream into your data that then gets decompressed.

Comment: Well, thank you, but I want to update the code where I use arrays directly instead of files, as in the first update, with what can I replace these steps? unsigned char NRBst[2];
 Resfile.read((char *)NRBst, 2 * sizeof(char));

Comment: When you switch to using just an array instead of the file you should be able to get rid of whats being done in these two lines. If you had an array of compressed data say for example of size 100 char, then the first two chars can just be thrown away and you can start indexing into your array at index 2. Essentially all these lines are doing is advancing the ifstream pointer by 2 chars.